# MySQL Concat (Length) with Alias

Tags: mysql, alias, concatenation

I have been formatting a select query into one giant string with set lengths:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(ulname,SPACE(15-LENGTH(ulname))))
FROM users WHERE ulname = 'Test'
```

But is it possible to do the same with a blank alias? If I were to do

```
Select '' AS CustomerID
```

I'm not exactly sure how I would set the spacing then. Would it be something like

```
CONCAT('' AS CustomerID, SPACE(10 - LENGTH(CustomerID)))?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    LEFT(CONCAT(ulname,SPACE(15)),15)
FROM test 
WHERE ulname = 'test';
```

Comment: I would like to concat '' AS CustomerID with a length restriction. My concat for the other fields seem to be ok

Comment: This should work for all your fields including single space values.

Comment: @CD Please run the query above and paste it to notepad ++ or something to examine the length of the output string.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I fed it back into the notepad and then it was fine. If I could ask one more thing? Would I be able to correct the length of a cast statement in the same way. I wasn't sure how to format the query. (i.e. CASE a.status
WHEN '0' THEN 'A'
WHEN '1' THEN 'T'
END AS 'Status')

Comment: Absolutely! You would need to wrap the case statement with the functions above:  `LEFT(CONCAT(CASE WHEN STATEMENT,SPACE(15)),15)` .

Comment: Thanks FutbloFan. I was getting frustrated searching around for this.

Comment: You bet! If you could please do me a favor and mark this as accepted answer, that would be great!